# Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer - can't find other players

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I bought Mass Effect a while ago and I didn't play multiplayer. Shepard died, I was unhappy with the ending, so I reloaded and now I'm trying to play multiplayer. I played at first without any of the multiplayer dlc's and I could find matches at any time of the day. Then I found out about the other DLCs and I downloaded all of them using the DLC pack, and now I can't find any other players online. My internet connection is wrong, and I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: I played a month ago, without any problems. Played with all free dlc, no others.

Comment: I play with all free DLC and still see people playing mayby you are playing at hours not many connect to play , here in europe i still find plenty of players

Comment: When you say your connection is wrong, do you mean on?

Answer (score 2):

For PC there is still a lot of players online all the time. 
For that make sure you go on Origin and install all the **free** DLC's - without those you won't find anyone.

If you can't find anyone, disable paid DLC's, as game only matches people with the same DLC settings.

Comment: Anna said that she installed all the free DLCs in the question. Additionally, there isn't any paid multiplayer DLC for Mass Effect 3; only in-game micro-transactions.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you playing on?  I play on Live and still get a decent amount of matches in short order.  It's nothing like what it used to be a couple years ago, but there's still people playing.

Answer (score 0):

If you install *any* multiplayer DLC, you need to install *all* the multiplayer DLC.

The multiplayer DLC is free and here are the names:

```
Resurgence
Rebellion
Earth
Retaliation
Reckoning
```

---

The matchmaking will only put you with players that have the exact same multiplayer DLC installed.  When you are just starting out, having no DLC is fine - because other players who are starting out will also have no DLC and you will be matched with them.

After a few matches, you should install all the DLC to unlock the ability to get the extra characters and weapons in your packs.